# EKS AWS Load Balancer Controller ALB support

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-elb, aws-load-balancer-controller

I have an EKS cluster created with [terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) and then I used helm to install the latest aws-load-balancer-controller:

```bash
✗ helm ls -n default
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                                   APP VERSION
ingress default         1               2023-05-22 12:18:13.099657 -0600 MDT    deployed        aws-load-balancer-controller-1.4.8      v2.4.7
```

From there, I am using the `helm create xx` command to create a helm chart for a node.js application.

When I specify the load balancer class as `alb` it is creating a Classic load balancer in AWS (with warnings to migrate).

```yaml
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 3000

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: |
      {"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}
```

Does the load balancer controller not support creating Application load balancers instead of Classic load balancers?  I believe I could accomplish all of the same in building the load balancer with Terraform but that doesn't feel like the right way to do things.